Can you use triangular tiles to form a rectangle of size 2016 cm by 2021 cm?
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

Jack has an unlimited number of tiles, each of which is in the shape of a right-angled triangle with side lengths 3 cm, 4 cm and 5 cm. Is it possible for Jack to combine a number of these tiles, without gaps or overlap, to form a rectangle of size 2016 cm by 2021 cm?

Attribution:  Intermediate Mathematical Olympiad Cayley paper 2021

Just curious - why all the down votes? It's obviously very simple,  but it's also clearly marked as being intended for beginners.

@NoeS Currently this puzzle has 2 upvotes and 5 downvotes.  My feeling is that some people feel that easy puzzles are inappropriate for this site. Some of my puzzles are easy and some are tough. I want to provide puzzles for beginners and experts.

There are a number of solutions, here is one:

 Assume the triangles are arranged in pairs to make 3 x 4 cm rectangles.
 The dimension 2016 is divisible by both 3 and 4.
 Suppose you make 7 strips each 3 cm wide in that direction.
 That leaves 2021 - 21 = 2000 cm remaining in the other direction.

 The area to be tiled is now 2016 x 2000 cm.
 2016 is divisible by 3 and 2000 is divisible by 4.
 So the area can be perfectly covered.

